# What's an easy way to use the MKDEV macro?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a minor and major numbers of a char device, and I want to turn them into `dev_t` (which used to hold device numbers), but I don't want to do all the process of building and writing a module, `insmod` it into the kernel and etc.

What's an easy way and fast to use the `MKDEV` macro?

```
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

dev_t device_num = MKDEV(int major, int minor);
```

Using a standard **C** program will not work, obviously, because it's *kernel-code/kernel-space.*

**Update**: Writing a User-Space program does work but I can't use the `dev_t` datatype, maybe because it can be used only by the kernel?

```
#include <linux/kdev_t.h> // MKDEV
#include <linux/types.h> // dev_t
#include <stdio.h> // I/O

int main(void)
{
    int device_id = MKDEV(10, 249);
    printf("%d\n", device_id); // 2809
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, your code should work even when compiled as a user space program.

Comment: Eh? I mean the code you post in the question should work. Both headers `linux/kdev_t.h` and `linux/types.h` are available for user space program. Just place `dev_t device_num = MKDEV(<major>, <minor>);` somewhere into the function body.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It works only when I not declare a variable with the `dev_t` datatype, maybe because it used only by the kernel? `error: unknown type name dev_t`

Comment: Yes, `dev_t` is for kernel only. But you may use any integer type instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yeah, I did use `integer` instead. Thank you! If you want to post an answer, you are welcome (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header [linux/kdev_t.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/include/uapi/linux/kdev_t.h) which provides `MKDEV` macro is accessible for user space programs too.

Definition of `dev_t` type is not accessible for the user space programs (headers `linux/types.h` are **different** for kernel and user), but for result of `MKDEV` you may use any integer type of 16 bit or more.

```
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>

<...>
int device_id = MKDEV(10, 249);
```